# VLCJ fails to toggle fullscreen

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, vlcj

if i directly use vlcj to show full screen then it's ok,but when i initially set a fixed size and later on the fly set it to full screen then it losts it's rendering,
code:

---

```
    panel_canvas=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel_canvas.add(windowsCanvas,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory("--no-video-title-show");
    mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();    
    mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(windowsCanvas));
    frame.setContentPane(panel_canvas);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(600,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

---

but if i use a process when press "enter" it will be full screen then it fails

```
        frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released ENTER"), "RELEASED_ENTER");
        frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("RELEASED_ENTER", new AbstractAction() {            
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
        if(!frame.isUndecorated()){
           pres_size=frame.getSize();               
           prev_location=frame.getLocation();
           frame.dispose();
           frame.setUndecorated(true);
           frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
           frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I apply the following method in my code to toggle full-screen in Swing:

```
int lastState = 0;
Rectangle lastBounds = null;

private void toggleDecoration(boolean decorated) {
    dispose();
    if (decorated) {
        //save last bounds and its extended state
        lastState = getExtendedState();
        lastBounds = getBounds();
        try{
            setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        }
        catch(Exception ev){
            setBounds(getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds());
            ev.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        //restore last bounds and its extended state
        setBounds(lastBounds);
        setExtendedState(lastState);
    }
    setUndecorated(decorated);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Usage:

```
decorated = !decorated;
toggleDecoration(decorated);
```

Comment: thanks @ee for reply.i am facing problem to full screen because of vlcj's "video surface" ,is ur code works for vlcj :) ,if yes ,can i get ur code that how u implement canvas with vlcj's video surface :)

Comment: I use the VLCJ's `DirectMediaPlayer` class that calls a VLCJ's `RenderCallbackAdapter.onDisplay()` method which allows the VLC video buffer to be painted as a `BufferedImage` instance via `Graphics.drawImage()` method inside a Swing frame's `paintComponent()` method (VLC 1.2.0, libVLC 1.1.11). This is available as a sample code in VLCJ's sample source library or on its tutorial site.

Comment: thanks again,trying to apply it,i'll give u feedback ,if i am successfull @ee

Comment: video_size is fixed because of rendercallback,is there any way to change the video size when i resized my jframe,thanks @ee.

Comment: Use the `BufferedImage` instance to scale/resize the video...this is what I do :)

Comment: To do it, modify the `BufferedImage` instance's width and height and apply `Graphics.scale()` on it

Comment: now,it has become a very slow player,cpu usage 30,memory usage is over 100,i just lost hope :( :(

Comment: @RafattouqirRafsun I don't know what you have tried. But, in my case, it works fine.

Comment: each time ur comment gives me hope,would plz share some of ur coding ,@ee

Comment: @RafattouqirRafsun Let see if I am free to check the codes that I did one year ago. But, this will be another issue (performance-related) which no longer fits the current issue, I guess :) May I know on what device you are trying to run your VLCJ codes? I did mine on a rugged UMPC with Atom CPU + 2GB RAM using libVLC 1.1.x + VLCJ 1.2.0. The CPU > 50 % are normal if you are streaming at higher bitrate beyond the possible bandwidth of the communication like over-the-air transmission @ 260 kbps limit. Try to stream using multicast-UDP. The memory usage can be reduced with `AffineTransform`

Comment: i am just making a desktop mediaplayer,i am having problem with defining the redercallback method,in which i have to set the super(widht*height) and the onDisplay method;

where widht and height have to be fixed and if i increase the amount of width and height then its quality is fine but memory usage goes high
on the other hand if i lower the size then video quality goes down
but player reacts quickly
one another thing i would like to mention that i use to draw image in a panel paint() method using g.drawImage(img,0,0,framewidht,frameheight,null);

Comment: @RafattouqirRafsun How big is the video output resolution that you are trying to achieve here? If it is too large, of course it will consume a lot of memory allocated to a Java application. If you don't give enough memory to your Java application, it may cause OOME.  In my application, the vid output in full-screen takes the device screen size of 640x480x32-bit-RGB from a BufferedImage instance. This is quite OK. But, if you are attempting a 1080p/720p full-screen HD res at 16:9/4:3 aspect ratio, you may have a performance issue since you are going through a JVM rather than a direct memorycall

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solved this way:

```js
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 public static void toogleFullScreen(JFrame mainWindow) {
  boolean isPlaying = mainWindow.mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
  if (isPlaying) {
   mainWindow.mediaPlayer.stop();
  }
  if (!mainWindow.isUndecorated()) {
   mainWindow.dispose();
   mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
   mainWindow.setUndecorated(true);
   GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
     .getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(mainWindow);
   BufferedImage cursorImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1,
     Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
   mainWindow.setCursor(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
     .createCustomCursor(cursorImage, new Point(0, 0),
       "InvisibleCursor"));
   mainWindow.setVisible(true);
   mainWindow.repaint();
  } else {
   GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment
     .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
   DisplayMode modo = device.getDisplayMode();
   mainWindow.dispose();
   mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
   mainWindow.setUndecorated(false);
   mainWindow.setBounds(modo.getWidth() / 2, modo.getHeight() / 2,
     modo.getWidth() / 2, modo.getHeight() / 2);
   device.setFullScreenWindow(null);
   mainWindow.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
   mainWindow.setVisible(true);
   mainWindow.repaint();
  }
  if (isPlaying) {
   mainWindow.mediaPlayer.start();
  }
 }
```

You just need stop the player while set FullScreen.